# What is correct way of authenticating and authorizing using cookie MVC asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key

I am making a custom login module for my application. I am using cookies to set the authentication and check cookie for authorization.

Now i want to set cookie, details are given below:

- I will create a cookie with http only
- Next i will use private and public key concept, public key will be encoded and added to cookie `Values` with a time stamp and username all encoded.
- I think i will encode like below:

  ```
  private static byte[] GenerateDigitalSignature(byte[] data,RSAParameters asymmetricKey)
  {
      using (var rcsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
      using (var cp = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
      {
          rcsp.ImportParameters(asymmetricKey);

          return rcsp.SignData(data, cp);
      }
  }
  ```
- And then upon login request i will decode it using the Private key and if the user is Authorize then i will allow the user to show the page.
- Right Now i am thinking to put my private and public key in web.config.

Can you please guide me is this correct implementation for login and setting cookie.

Also can you put an example to ***set cookie*** with three parameters viz. Public key, Datetime and UserName and ***decode*** it using private key

I am setting my cookie like below:

```
System.Web.HttpCookie loginCookie1 = new System.Web.HttpCookie("loginCookie");
    Response.Cookies["loginCookie1"].Values = new Dictionary<String, String>()
                        {
                            {"PublicKey", "Abc"},
                            {"DateTime", DateTime.Now.ToString()}
                        };
```

It is giving me error though, it is conversion error.

```
Dictionaty<string,string> to NameValueCollection
```

Thank you

Comment: Am i adding level of complexity which is not required?

Comment: Cookie is just a text file sent back and forth between the server and the client. Value is string. You can concatenate strings with some delimiter like ';' (taking your example: "Abc;12/22/2015") and encode the whole string. After decoding, split the string by that delimiter.

Comment: Any reason for not using the standard ASP.NET forms authentication module?

Comment: It is MVC so i think what i can use is Asp.net Identity but that what i have decided to make my own module for login. No specific reason though

Comment: take look this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kybcs83h.aspx will guide you

Comment: Thank you but this is not what i want!!

Comment: Ok lemme write code according the link will tell you

Comment: I do not think i can get the value of the cookie then if i use above method or atleast i am not able to find way to get value.